# How to compare column, and define it it's increasing or decreasing in value?

Tags: excel

For  a example, I have these columns:

```
| name  | col1 | col2 | 
|-------|------|------|
| base1 | 2    | 3    | 
| base2 | 2    | 2    |
```

I want to use a  `conditional formatting` to, in the `col2` to show an Up arrow, or a Down arrow, checking the previous column to see if the value it's bigger, or lower, or 0.

How can I achieve this? I'm creating a lot of settings but I can't achieve this.

---

EDIT1:

So, I see I got some good answers. But I will need to do something like this:[image]

These are sizes of my sql server databases. I would like to compare `D1` with `B1`, and `E1` with `C1`. But then, after this first compare, I would like to compare `F1` with  `D1` and `G1` with `E1`. I don't think this is posible with a formula, it will be something really manual. I just want to compare the last value, with the previous one, to see how's the growth is, well, growing.

Comment: I could make with, row by row, and i'm having problems to apply to the entire collumn.

Comment: Should be able to adapt my answer fairly easily, just put D1>B1 in the conditional format rule and copy it across - then it will change to E1>C1 etc. by relative addressing.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it from first principles using a format like

```
#↑
```

and a formula like

```
=B1>A1
```

[image]

getting the up and down arrow from a spare cell where I've used Insert Symbol

Comment: Thanks, appreciated.